# How do you open and use a .php file within a .html file.

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, csv

Right so I've look around on the net but I couldn't find anything that tells me how to basically open and use a .php file in a .html file. For this assignment it is compulsory that I use a .html but I want to read a .csv file and append the data within it into a table but I only know how to do that in php. Is there a way to do this without touching the htaccess?

Comment: Use AJAX in HTML to load the returned content from PHP file

Comment: Can you re-check your assignment's wording? "Use HTML" is a sensible assignment. "Use a .html file" is less so. If it really is the latter, @Thamilan's answer is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```